# how to prove that the minor axis of the ellipse is the radius of the cylinder

Tags: geometry

Consider the following wedge

[image] cut from a cylinder of radius r.
The plane that cuts the wedge goes through the very bottom of the cylinder leading to an ellipse as the cross section of the wedge.

The long axis of the ellipse is $2R$ in length.

How can I prove that the minor axis of the ellipse is $2r$ in length where $r$ is the radius of the cylinder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the usual rectangular coordinate system xyz with origin at the middle of the ellipse.
The x axis is perpendicular to the cylinder and pointing towards the viewer. The y axis runs along the axis of the cylinder and the z axis is perpendicular to the y axis on the plane of the paper.

The equation of the cylinder is

$$x^{2}+z^{2}=r^{2}$$

Consider the vector from the origin to the bottom of the cylinder in the direction of the major axis of the ellipse. Its coordinates are

$(0,R\sin\theta,-R\cos\theta)$

Consider the vector from the origin to the back of the ellipse in the direction of the minor axis of the ellipse. Its coordinates are

$$(-a,0,0)$$

where $a$ is the minor axis of the ellipse.

A vector perpendicular to these two and therefore perpendicular to the ellipse is $$(0,Rr\cos\theta,Rr\sin\theta)$$. Therefore the equation of the plane on which the ellipse lies is

$$y\cos\theta + z\sin\theta=0$$

The ellipse is the intersection of this plane with the cylinder $x^{2}+z^{2}=r^{2}$. Thus the ellipse is described by these 2 equations in this set of rectangular coordinates. Notice that $\cos\theta=r/R, \sin\theta=\sqrt{R^{2}-r^{2}}/r$.

Consider the farthest back point along the minor axis of the eclipse. I mentioned before that it has coordinates $(-a,0,0)$ or $x=-a$.

If you replace this in the equations of the ellipse you get $a=r$ and therefore the minor axis of the ellipse has the same length as the radius of the cylinder.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question and the diagram (and this could be a long shot...), this seems to be pretty straightforward: no matter where that ellipse's center is, if you take the two extreme points of the minor axis they will be two antipode points on the cylinder, no matter what the angle $\;\theta\;$ is,  and thus this minor axis's length is $\;2r\;$ .

Comment: You are saying that this is evident if the plane cutting the edge goes through the bottom of the cylinder?

Comment: @JennyToy I'm not sure I understand your question. What I understand of what you wrote and of the diagram is that we *always* begin at one of the cylinder's extreme points ( which in the diagram would be the lower point close to $\;\theta\;$) , and then, **leaving that point fixed**, we make the perpendicular (to the basis, if you will) slant towards the inner part of the cylinder but parallel to the symmetry axis, and then we cut the cylinder with that plane.

Comment: I think you are right and it must be self evident, but I fail to see why it is evident. Perhaps if I could derive the equation of the plane, find the intersection of the plane with the cylinder I would then see that the intersection is an ellipse with minor radius $r$.